# Экранирование данных PDO php

Tags: pdo, php_pdo, php

Правильно ли в данной function экранируются передаваемые данные? Возможен ли другой способ экранирования ? bindparam  не работает для $DBH->query

```
 public function CheckAuth($email, $password)
{

    $DBH = Registry::get('DBH');
    try {

        $email = $DBH->quote($email);
        $password = $DBH->quote($password);
        $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE mail=$email AND password =$password");

        $result = $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {

            return $row['id'];

        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Если вы используете эту функцию для построения SQL запросов, настоятельно рекомендуется пользоваться методом PDO::prepare() для подготовки запроса с псевдопеременными вместо использования PDO::quote() для вставки данных введенных пользователем в SQL запрос. Подготавливаемые запросы с параметрами не только компактней, удобней, устойчивей к SQL иньекциям, но и работают быстрее, нежели вручную построенные запросы, так как и клиент и сервер могут кэшировать такие запросы в уже скомпилированном виде.

[доки PDO::quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.quote.php)

> bindparam не работает для $DBH->query

И еще раз к докам. Такой [метод](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php) (а точнее, `bindParam`) есть у `PDOStatement`, и в его же описании находятся [примеры](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php#example-957) его использования - `PDOStatement` возвращается методом `PDO::prepare()`. А про `query()` можно уже из названия догадаться, что он выполняет запрос **здесь и сейчас**, не говоря уж, простите мою привязанность, о [доках](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php).

Comment: доки для слабаков, лучше на форуме спросить